# Read SQL Transaction Log via T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my script for read SQL transactions log (offline log) from backup file.

I want to get all **INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE** are executed by T-SQL ( exclude the action is using GUI of SSMS)

```
DECLARE @From DATETIME, @To DATETIME
DECLARE @FilePath NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @FilePath = N'D:\abc.BAK'
SET @From ='2015/10/01 00:00:00'
SET @To ='2015/10/31 00:00:00'

SELECT *
INTO #Log
FROM fn_dump_dblog (
        NULL, NULL, N'DISK', 1, @FilePath,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
        
SELECT  l.[Transaction Name],
            objectName.schemaname AS [Schema],
            objectName.name AS [Object],
        SUSER_SNAME (l.[Transaction SID]) AS [User],
        l.[Begin Time],
        endTime.[End Time],
        l.[Transaction ID]        
FROM #Log AS l
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT l.[Transaction ID], l.[End Time]
            FROM #Log AS l
            WHERE Operation = 'LOP_COMMIT_XACT'       
) AS endTime ON l.[Transaction ID] = endTime.[Transaction ID]
INNER JOIN(
      SELECT [Transaction ID],AllocUnitName  FROM #Log AS l
      WHERE AllocUnitName IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY [Transaction ID], AllocUnitName
) AS alloc ON l.[Transaction ID] = alloc.[Transaction ID]
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT i.object_id, i.name AS IndexName,o.name,s.name+'.'+o.name+'.'+i.name AS keyname,s.name AS schemaname FROM sys.indexes AS i
      INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
      INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
) AS objectName ON alloc.AllocUnitName = objectName.keyname
WHERE Operation = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
      AND [Transaction Name] IN ('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE')
      AND l.[Begin Time] BETWEEN @From AND @To
ORDER BY l.[Transaction ID]

DROP TABLE #Log
```

So the questions are:

1. I have already tested this script and it work well for most of cases. Do you know are there any missed case?
2. Do you have any better solution for this case?

   Thanks for your contributions